# Set Item level permissions in the SharePoint form library when an InfoPath form is submitted

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

I have a form library in my site. I have submitted the InfoPath form. The form should visible to only the person who created it and also to people defined in the InfoPath form.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

In order to set the permissions on the item based on the people defined on the InfoPath form, you need to create custom Event Handler on the list that will modify the permissions when new items are added (ItemAdded event).

[This](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/managing-itemupdating-and-itemupdated-events-firing-twice-in-a-sharepoint-item-event-receiver/) will give you the required details on event handlers, while [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358647/programatically-add-user-permission-to-a-list-in-sharepoint) shows how to grant permissions programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

1: Under Advanced settings of the library you can limit the person to view only their items or if you want custom permissions then follow (2)

2: You can create a workflow that runs after an item is submitted which breaks the permissions of the item and assigns new permissions.
Use SP designer workflow or Nintex.

Here is a link to break item level permissions using SP Designer workflow
http://spcycle.blogspot.com.au/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html

Useful Sharepoint Designer Custom Workflow Activities
http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/